# Get website's server from IP address

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I have a function that returns a website's server when you enter the url for the site:

```
private string GetWebServer()
{
    string server = string.Empty;

    //get URL
    string url = txtURL.Text.Trim().ToLower();
    if (!url.StartsWith("http://") && !url.StartsWith("https://"))
        url = "http://" + url;

    HttpWebRequest request = null;
    HttpWebResponse response = null;

    try
    {
        request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        server = response.Headers["Server"];
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        server = "Unknown";
    }
    finally
    {
        if (response != null)
        {
            response.Close();
        }
    }

    return server;
}
```

I'd like to also be able to get a website's server from the IP address instead of the site's url. But if I enter an IP address, I get an error saying "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined." when calling WebRequest.Create(url).

Does someone know how I can modify this to accomplish what I want?

Comment: are you trying to get the server name from a client inside the domain?

Comment: are you trying to get the server name of some site you are browsing at home, for instance www.google.com, or are you trying to get the name of a server on YOUR domain that you are connected to?

Comment: I'm trying to get the server name of any site that I'm browsing to, like www.microsoft.com. The page takes a url from the user, and it returns the server. I'd like to modify it so that the user enters an IP address instead of a url, and it returns the server.

Comment: Could you give an example of URL where you have a problem? At least with all I tested everything works OK. http://207.46.170.123/Downloads/en/default.aspx (http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/en/default.aspx) returns "Microsoft-IIS/7.5" for example.
By the way response.Headers["Server"] == response.Server.

Comment: He's getting the server that attended the reqest, like "Microsoft-IIS/7.5" or "Apache/2.2.12 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.12 OpenSSL/0.9.7d mod_wsgi/3.2 Python/2.6.5rc2". The Server response header.

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise you could lookup the name from the IP address and then use the address in your other calls:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1").HostName.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using this same method when using an IP address?  This error will be thrown if you don't have "http://" prepended to the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

A single IP can serve multiple domains. You will not have a 1:1 mapping. What you are trying to do is a reverse DNS lookup. There are many webservices that provide an incomplete list of domains that are served from a IP. Once I had to use a combination of them to get a more complete list.

Here is a small list of such sites:

1. http://remote.12dt.com/
2. http://www.guerrilladns.com/

And I already used the following DNS lookup that also finds other domains served by the same IP:

1. http://www.robtex.com/dns/